# Store different templated classes in one container without losing information about it's type

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I'm currently working on a project where a client part of my application has to be able to create custom templated classes on the server. The server part has to keep track of these created classes and has to remember the types with which the classes has been instantiated. The problem is, that there are around 36 different class-template-combinations that are valid in my application. I'm currently struggling to keep track of these different types in a collection without losing information about my instances.

I'm currently using something like this:

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

enum class data_type : std::uint8_t {
    type_int = 1,
    type_float,
    type_double
};

enum class class_type : std:: uint8_t {
    type_A = 1,
    type_B
};

struct X {
    virtual data_type get_data_type() = 0;
    virtual class_type get_class_type() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct A : X {
    data_type get_data_type() override
    {
        if (std::is_same<T, int>::value) {
            return data_type::type_int;
        } else if (std::is_same<T, float>::value) {
            return data_type::type_float;
        } else if (std::is_same<T, double>::value) {
            return data_type::type_double;
        } else {
            /* ... */
        }
    }

    class_type get_class_type() override
    {
        return class_type::type_A;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct B : X {
    data_type get_data_type() override
    {
        if (std::is_same<T, int>::value) {
            return data_type::type_int;
        } else if (std::is_same<T, float>::value) {
            return data_type::type_float;
        } else if (std::is_same<T, double>::value) {
            return data_type::type_double;
        } else {
            /* ... */
        }
    }

    class_type get_class_type() override
    {
        return class_type::type_B;
    }
};

struct Storage {

    template <typename T, template <typename> class Class>
    void create() {
        Class<T>* t = new Class<T>();
        _classes.push_back(std::unique_ptr<X>(t));
    }

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<X>> _classes;
};
```

but I'm wondering if this is the way to go or if there is a more elegant way. Here I would have to always switch through the `enum`s to get the full type out of my Storage class, something like:

```
switch(_classes.front()->get_class_type()) {
case class_type::type_A:
{
    switch(_classes.front()->get_data_type()) {
    case data_type::type_int:
    {
         /* I finally know that it is A<int> */
    }
/* ... */
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `std::variant` ?

Comment: Would [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/W1Dk1C4A3ubC04mS) work for you?

Comment: Really helpful. Thank you for your input @skypjack

Comment: I'd combine this with the design of @Curious; your design @skypjack would indeed make it quite easy to resolve the template types of `A` or `B`

Comment: @reedts Added it as an answer for future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider using `std::variant` and the `std::visit` pattern

```
auto var = std::variant<int, float, double>{};
// assign var to value
std::visit([](auto& value) {
    using Type = std::decay_t<decltype(value)>;
    if constexpr (std::is_same<Type, int>{}) {
        // is an int
    } else if (std::is_same<Type, float>{}) {
        // is float
    } else if (std::is_same<Type, double>{}) {
        // is double
    }
}, var);
```

If the `if constexpr` looks ugly to you then you can substitute it with a handrolled visitor class as well.

```
class Visitor {
public:
    void operator()(int& value) { ... }
    void operator()(float& value) { ... }
    void operator()(double& value) { ... }
};

auto var = std::variant<int, float, double>{};
// assign var to value
std::visit(Visitor{}, var);
```

Comment: I think I get your idea but I'm not sure if it is applicable if I have 2 levels of "templatenes". So, in my case I would have something like this (?):

`std::vector<std::variant<A<int>, A<float>, A<double>>`

**EDIT**: Please correct me if I'm misunderstanding

Comment: @reedts if you have `A` instantiated with `int`, `double` and `float` you can just replace the `is_same` to compare with `A<int>`, `A<double>` and `A<float>` instead

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful! I'm thinking about combining this design with the one provided by @skypjack

Comment: @Curious Every `constexpr if` will evaluate to `false` because `decltype(value)` is a reference.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments to the question, this is a viable approach that could help:

```
#include<vector>
#include<memory>

struct Counter {
    static int next() {
        static int v = 0;
        return v++;
    }
};

template<typename>
struct Type: Counter {
    static int value() {
        static const int v = Counter::next();
        return v;
    }
};

struct X {
    virtual int get_data_type() = 0;
    virtual int get_class_type() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct A : X {
    int get_data_type() override {
        return Type<T>::value();
    }

    int get_class_type() override {
        return Type<A<T>>::value();
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct B : X {
    int get_data_type() override {
        return Type<T>::value();
    }

    int get_class_type() override {
        return Type<B<T>>::value();
    }
};

struct Storage {
    template <typename T, template <typename> class Class>
    void create() {
        Class<T>* t = new Class<T>();
        _classes.push_back(std::unique_ptr<X>(t));
    }

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<X>> _classes;
};

int main() {
    Storage s;
    s.create<int, A>();

    if(Type<int>::value() == s._classes.front()->get_class_type()) {
        //...
    };
}
```

See it running on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/W1Dk1C4A3ubC04mS).